# GLFW not initializing on arch linux

Tags: c++, glfw

I'm trying to build a glfw window on arch linux with gnome. But every time I try running the app it is not able to initialize the window and it just prints *before init* but not *after init*.

I build it with gcc:

```
gcc -o app main.c -lglfw -lGLU -lGL -lm
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {
    GLFWwindow* window;
    printf("before init\n");
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;
    printf("after init\n");

    window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Hello World", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), NULL);

    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you have installed? `glfw-wayland` or `glfw-x11` Compiles (and runs) just fine on Arch with `glfw-x11` installed and `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o app glfwx-test.c -lglfw -lGLU -lGL -lm` You can do `pacman -Q | grep '^glfw'` to check what you have.

Comment: Thanks! This worked! It turns out I've had glfw-wayland and not glfw-x11.

Comment: Glad it helped. Oof -- don't run it in a remote virtualbox guest -- things get ugly `:)` Virtualbox evidently doesn't appreciate switching between native X and the glfw graphics. Works fine on the host.